# How can I generate a legend for a BubbleChart?

Tags: plotting, graphics, legending, visualization

Is there a way to make a nice disk radius legend (with linear or log scale) for a `BubbleChart`?

Something like the following example should be built in:

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since `BubbleChart` does the scaling of the bubbles the trick is to let it draw the circles of the legend too. I do that by adding the legend circles to the plot data. The rest of the graphics can be added using `Show`.

```
lc = Append[Reverse@CityData[#, "Coordinates"], 
            CityData[#, "Population"]
     ] & /@ CityData[{Large, "USA"}];

steps = 8;
legendCircles = Table[{-120 + 18/steps i^1.25, 22, 1000000 i}, {i, steps}];
text = Table[Text[i, {-120 + 18/steps i^1.25, 19}], {i, steps}];

Show[
  Graphics[{FaceForm[LightGray], EdgeForm[Black], 
            CountryData["USA", "Polygon"], text,
            Text[Style["Population (mln)", FontFamily -> "Arial", Bold, 16]]}, 
            PlotRange -> {{-126`, -66}, {17, 51}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic
  ], 
  BubbleChart[Join[lc, legendCircles], BubbleScale -> "Area", 
              AspectRatio -> Automatic, BubbleSizes -> {0.01, 0.1}
  ]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

or with labels shifted to appear in the bubbles:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**A note on combining BubbleChart graphics with other graphics**

You might have noticed the above use of `AspectRatio` and `PlotRange`. They were pretty much essential. Since `BubbleChart` uses the `AspectRatio` of its plot to determine the eccentricity of the ovals it draws (yes, it draws ovals: check its `FullForm`), it is important to watch the aspect ratio of a combined plot carefully.

For instance, let's see what happens if we start from scratch and want to have a cartographic projection different from the simple "Equirectangular" lat,long coordinate system used above.

```
(* conversion of city locations to Mercator projection *)
lc = Append[
     GeoGridPosition[
       GeoPosition[
        Append[CityData[#, "Coordinates"], 
          CityData[#, "Elevation"]] /. Missing["NotAvailable"] -> 0], 
       "Mercator"][[1, ;; 2]]
     , CityData[#, "Population"]
     ] & /@ CityData[{Large, "USA"}];

(* CountryData has a built-in projection conversion for its country polygon:     *)
(* CountryData["USA", {"Polygon","projection"}]                                  *)
(* but it results in a grid system different from the GeoGridPosition conversion *)
(* So, I'll perform the transformation in the same way as above                  *)
USAplot = 
 Graphics[{FaceForm[LightGray], EdgeForm[Darker@Gray], 
   Apply[
      GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition[{#2, #1, 0}],"Mercator"][[1, ;; 2]] &,     
      CountryData["USA", "Polygon"], 
      {3}
   ]}]

cityPlot = BubbleChart[lc, BubbleSizes -> {0.01, 0.1}];
Show[USAplot, cityPlot]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can prevent this from happening by *borrowing the background graphics' options* when making the `BubbleChart` plot:

```
cityPlot = 
 BubbleChart[lc, AbsoluteOptions[USAplot, {AspectRatio, PlotRange}],BubbleSizes -> {0.01, 0.1}];

Show[USAplot, cityPlot, AbsoluteOptions[USAplot, {AspectRatio, PlotRange}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: its the wrong colour! ;-)

Comment: @Chris If you were referring to political color you may want to read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_states_and_blue_states

Answer (score 16):

Many legends can be easily created using combination of Row and Column, where for example, each Row contains two elements: a Graphics expression, and a text label which need *not* be wrapped in `Text`.

However, since the label you want involves size coding, this method doesn't work. Further, you want to match the size of `Disks` in the main graphics to the size in the legend, so I recommend using Epilog or Inset.

The basic layout of the legend itself is straightforward, up to scaling:

```
 Graphics[{Lighter@Blue, Table[{Disk[{i, 0}, Sqrt[i/Pi]/3],
    Black, Text[Style[i, FontSize -> 14], {i, -2/3}]}, {i, 1, 5}]}]
```

[image]

The scaling factor is up to you. For area-coding, the `Sqrt` is necessary since Disk is determined by radius, but typically the factor `Pi` is irrelevant since that's a constant parameter that only affects absolute size not relative size. Note the additional factor of 3 shrinking to avoid the disks From overlapping.

Here's a more compact legend using stacked Circles:

```
Graphics[{Lighter@Blue, Table[{Circle[{0, Sqrt[i/Pi]}, Sqrt[i/Pi]],
    Lighter@Gray,
    Line[{{1/4, 2 Sqrt[i/Pi]}, {2 - 1/4, 2 Sqrt[i/Pi]}}],
    Black,
    Text[Style[i, FontSize -> 14], {2, 2 Sqrt[i/Pi]}]}, {i, 1, 10}]},
 ImageSize -> 300
 ]
```

[image]